# How to calculate P-value and 95% confidence interval in R for cross-sectional table

Tags: r, confidence-interval, p-value

I am a newbie to statistics and R. Need someone's help to understand how to get a 95% confidence interval and p-value from the above data to test the null hypothesis that there is no difference in FUS prevalence according to a DFS status. Above I used, epi.2by2 cross-sectional method.

```
    install.packages("epiR");library(epiR)
    tab <- matrix(c(13,2163,5,3349), nrow = 2, ncol=2); rownames(tab) <- c("DF+", "DF-"); colnames(tab) <- c("FUS+", "FUS-"); epi.2by2(dat = as.table(tab), method = "cross.sectional", digits = 2, conf.level = 0.95, units = 100, interpret = FALSE, outcome = "as.columns")
         


result as below
      FUS+   FUS-
DF+   13      5
DF-   2163    3349


             Outcome +    Outcome -      Total        Prevalence *        Odds
Exposed +           13            5         18                72.2       2.600
Exposed -         2163         3349       5512                39.2       0.646
Total             2176         3354       5530                39.3       0.649

Point estimates and 95% CIs:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Prevalence ratio                               1.84 (1.38, 2.46)
Odds ratio                                     4.03 (1.43, 11.31)
Attrib prevalence in the exposed *             32.98 (12.25, 53.71)
Attrib fraction in the exposed (%)             45.67 (27.50, 59.28)
Attrib prevalence in the population *          0.11 (-1.71, 1.93)
Attrib fraction in the population (%)         0.27 (0.06, 0.49)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Uncorrected chi2 test that OR = 1: chi2(1) = 8.177 Pr>chi2 = 0.004
Fisher exact test that OR = 1: Pr>chi2 = 0.006
 Wald confidence limits
 CI: confidence interval
 * Outcomes per 100 population units
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have all of this above in your output though you have so many numbers I can see how this could be confusing to interpret. To simply things, you could just utilize Fisher's exact test from base R like this:

```
tab <- matrix(c(13,2163,5,3349), nrow = 2, ncol=2)
fisher.test(tab)
```

You outputs should look like this:

data:  tab
p-value = 0.006351
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
1.344086 14.439890
sample estimates:
odds ratio
4.024588

Here you have the p-value for Fisher's exact test as well as the estimated odds ratio (4.024) and a 95 percent confidence interval for the odds ratio (1.34 - 14.43).

Comment: Thank you so much. Its really help me :)